# armv7 iphone warnings

Tags: iphone, xcode4, warnings, armv7, ios32

I get the following warnings when trying to build my project. There are about 160 warnings similar to them which is annoying

> ld: warning: CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_ALL subtype is deprecated: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_udivsi3.o)

and

> warning: (armv7) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o) object file '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for armv7.

All of the warnings are related to libgcc.a.

I need this application to support iOS 3.2 and later. So what can I do to remove these warnings?

Comment: ARMv6 code will work on iOS 3.2 and later. If for some reason you're using an ARMv6-only library, it'll run on new devices.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan, you should post your comment as an answer so that this doesn't show up in the "unanswered questions" list, and so Sami can "accept" it and give you the credit/reputation you deserve.

Comment: Eh, it's not a complete answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two different things - your deployment target and your base SDK.  Your deployment target defines which iOS versions you intend to run on.  Set your base SDK to the latest version available.  Set your deployment target to iOS 3.2.

Having said that, for almost all cases, I think it's probably a mistake to target iOS 3 these days.  iOS 6 is about to be released, and almost everybody has upgraded beyond iOS 3.2.  Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: This is an old question, about 1 year and 5 months ago. These warnings disappeared with newer versions. I now support iOS 4.3 and later.